# 5 Day Countdown Timer with LED Indicators

Tags: led

Basically, I would like to make a timer that counts down from 1 to 5 days, with each day represented as a LED. There should be a single button that each time pressed causes the timer to go up a day and indicate that by illuminating the LED representing that Day, then countdown to 0 days from there. The LEDs would only illuminate in the presence of light, so it would require a light sensor. It should also be battery-operated.

If someone could provide a high level roadmap, or even something more specific, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: We are not here to offer designs on request. What designs have you found sofar that might do the job or could be altered to do so. Design requests without any effort from your side have a high risk of being closed.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: Understood! I simply don't have a clue where to start. A 555 timer won't do -- I'm assuming I need a microcontroller. I can't find anything online after about four weeks of searching, so I came here hoping someone could be helpful!

Comment: How about using an Arduino? Plenty of on-line help material.. If you want to go the hardware-only route, look at 555 (or another oscillator), counter(s), and a 3-to-8 decoder/demultiplexer.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I am looking at this right now -- funny you recommend that! It's been five years since I last made a circuit, so to say I'm rusty is an understatement. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: How accurate does this thing have to be?  That is, if you push the button , say, five times and the day 5 LED turns ON, how close must it be  to  24 hours (plus or minus) when the day 5 LED goes OFF and the day 4 LED turns ON?

Comment: @EMFields Thanks for participating. It doesn't need to be accurate really at all -- I mean, within 5-15 minutes off would be fine.

Also, the first four LEDs would stay illuminated, but the fifth would turn off in this instance.

Thanks again!

Comment: +/- 15 minutes out of 24 hours is  +/- 1 part in 96 which, at close to 1% isn't exactly sloppy.  +/- 5 minutes comes out to be about  +/- 0.35%, so instead of an analog timer like a 555 you may want go with something you don't have to fiddle with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose to go the microcontroller route, the circuit is quite simple:

[image]

I've chosen to use a [PIC16F676](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40039F.pdf), but any small processor would do.  It comes in a user friendly 14-pin DIP package.

This circuit is pretty complete except for a header to program the chip via a [PICkit 3](http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=PG164130) or equivalent and the 5V power supply.

The firmware should be pretty simple; set the µC to run as slow as possible to conserve power by using the 32 kHz clock.  Set up a one second interrupt, and inside the ISR, increment a 32-bit counter.  If it reaches 86,400, decrement the day counter if greater than zero and reset the seconds counter to 0.

Also inside the ISR, briefly turn on the op-amp using output pin RC5 (used to conserve power, rather than leaving the op-amp on all the time).  Check if the photodiode is sensing light or not, and turn on the appropriate LED based on whether there is light or not.  Turn off the op-amp.

You don't want to restrict scanning of the pushbuttons to the once per second ISR, as this would provide poor responsiveness; note that I put both of them on Port A which means you can use the IOC (interrupt on change) feature of the µC.  You will need to define a second ISR to handle that.  When you see a button press, wait 50 ms and check again (software debouncing) and if still pressed, increment the day counter if less than five.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would like it to be battery-operated. Ultimately, I would like the LEDS to stay lit only in light, so therefore it wouldn't use any power for LEDs when in darkness. This is actually critical to the design -- I apologize for not mentioning it.

I would imagine doing that would only require adding an additional photocell sensor and a switch?

Comment: @AllenGingrich The PIC16F676 consumes very little power; when it is asleep the timer only draws 4 µA.  I'll let you add the sensor and whatever else you need; pin 12 (RA1) and pin 11 (RA2) would be good candidates for expansion.

Comment: 5 LEDs instead of 3, and some code would be nice...

Comment: @EMFields I updated my answer to include the two missing LED's, added a circuit for the photo sensor and second pushbutton (if needed), and wrote up a description of the  firmware.

Comment: Very nicely done! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one in hardware that simulates decently, and here's an overview, instead of a detailed circuit description of how it's supposed to work:

V6, in the lower left-hand corner, is a 1 Hz oscillator ( a couple of dollars from DigiKey) and U1 and U28 on the upper left are two 12 bit ripple counters cascaded so they'll count to 86400, the number of seconds in a day.

With no hot LEDs in the queue, the counter will be inhibited and held in reset by the zero on U8Q8,

The queue comprises U3 and U4, two cascaded four-bit bidirectonal universal shift registers, and  U2, U5, U6, U7, and U8;  all inverters, and all used to drive the LEDs without loading U3 and U4's outputs.

U3 and U4 are used like a LIFO stack, in that since the right-shift serial input is connected to Vcc, when the pushbutton is pressed a logical one will be pushed onto the stack and light the "day 1" LED if the queue was previously empty.

If it wasn't, it'll push all the ones in the queue farther up the stack, until it gets full, and when that happens U23 and U24 will report to U22 that the queue is full and will kill the pushbutton input to the system until the day counter counts the day down to four or less.

Once the pushbutton is released, the previously reset day counter works by up-counting one-second clock pulses until it gets to 86400 (15180 hex) then, when it gets there, U27 and U29 will decode the count and send a pulse to the queue which causes it to shift left. Since the left shift serial input is hard-wired to zero volts and the queue was earlier cleared, the output from the decoder will shift the contents of the queue one bit to the left, which will extinguish the most significant LED.

Note that at any time the queue isn't full, pushing the pushbutton will result in resetting the day counter and pushing the stack, lighting up another LED and starting the timing sequence anew.

That means, for example, if LED 4 was only one second away from countdown to zero, when the pushbutton is pressed LED 5 will light, LED 4's timeout will be cancelled, and the new timeout will set to one day for each LED, for a new total of  five days.

The stuff in the upper middle is a latching muxer used to select between either the pushbutton as the right shift clock or the timer as the left-shift clock.

The circuit to the right of bottom center is  a voltage comparator with an on-board reference, and it functions by turning off all of the illuminated LEDs when night time encroaches without interfering with the timer function.

[image]

Just for grins, here's a shot of the circuit I used to simulate the timer and get a plot its output. I added a second pushbutton sequence and changed  the length of the timeout and the clock frequency in order to get something conveniently viewable, but other than that both circuits are identical and [here's a link to the files you'll need](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sa9fmrrk182n1jh/AABoxrK-n50CEvKaCxFa2qxOa?dl=0) if you want to play with the circuit.

Just download them all into the same folder and left click on the .asc file to to start LTspice and bring up the schematic editor.

[image]

Comment: @Olin Lathrop Then why don't you provide one instead of complaining.  I'm sure you have the skill to do so.  I do not or I would.

Comment: @mike: Tcrosley already did, so I upvoted his instead of writing my own.